# How to disable zoom functionality on a React.js app running in a docker container in a Debian environment?

Tags: reactjs, linux, docker, zooming

I have a react.js app which I want to make not possible to zoom on each page. I did this and it worked for me when i was running it locally on my Windows machine  in vscode. Then I deployed it to my docker container which runs a Linux environment in itself and itself runs on a computer that runs Debian and zoom was possible although as I said locally that was not possible.

I have basically added this line in my code in the React.js app and more specifically the `user-scalable=no` and that made everything work.

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

Why does this not work in my docker container and how can I make it work so that zooming is not possible anymore?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand 100%. Are you asking about the same browser accessing a site running locally vs in docker, or a local browser behaving differently than a Linux browser?

Comment: I have this react app. I develop it locally on my laptop and then test it. Locally the above mentioned prohibiting of zoom worked so it was not possible to zoom on any page. Then I build a docker container but I built it on another machine which is linux. This container is my react app. The zooming works there and it should not. Questions is how to stop it from working @DaveNewton

Comment: So using the same browser you connect to the app running locally and it works, you connect to the app running in Docker it doesn't work? That's odd, since assuming the browser gets the same responses it should behave the same. What else might be different?

Comment: It is not the same browser, it is a browser on another machine. But they are both chromium.

Comment: Are they the exact same browser/version/OS/etc or are they different?

Comment: Different OS, version and  browser are the same.